# telegram bot cannot remove notification when delete message in group

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Expected:

Bot sendMessage -> User receive notification

Bot deleteMessage -> Telegram in app message deleted -> User received notification will be disappear

---

but when i add telegram bot to **group**

Bot sendMessage -> User receive notification

Bot deleteMessage -> Telegram in app message deleted -> User received notification does ***not disappear***

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be done, since having the Notification is an OS feature, not the app itself. A bot cannot remove already received notifications.